# Russian Translation of Meam Loez

Tags: jewish-books, midrash, translation

The book, Meam Loez, written by Yaakov Culi in Ladino, has been translated into many languages. Has it been translated into Russian? If so, where can it be found? I know many Russians that would be helped by this book.

Comment: I changed the name to Culi to make it consistent with the much much more popular transliteration. (other than this page, I found only 1 google page with Juli as opposed to 2800 for Culi) If you don't like the change, just [change](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/75915/edit) it back.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0013_0_13482.html):

> Yalkut Me-Am Lo'ez has been translated into a number of other languages, including Russian.

Answer (score 1):

Seems difficult to find the Russian version you are looking for. The ones I found are: the [Me'am Lo'ez Haggadah](http://www.nehora.com/the-meam-loez-haggadah-ashkenazi-russian/) and [Tisha Be'Av](http://www.israelbookshop.com/judaica-books/Meam_Loez_9Av_Rus.html). I don't know much about these versions and can only tell you that they look based on Meam Loez.